# Start animation from right when leaving screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to have an animation that starts in the center but loops infinitely. As you can see in the snippet the cubes first start in the center, dispersed evenly across the width, but what I want is that the moment the cube leaves the screen on the left, it starts back at the right, so it is seamless. Anyone knows how to do this?

Here's the code:

```css
#skillIcon {
  animation: moveLeft 5s linear infinite;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#444;
  align-items:center;
  position:relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveLeft {
  from {
    right: -30%;
  }
  to {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

#parentDiv{
background-color:#222;
display:flex;
position:relative;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
<div id="skillIcon">
</div>
<div id="skillIcon">
</div>
<div id="skillIcon">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're on the right track, the keys frames is the trick

```
@keyframes example {
  0%   {left:50%;}
  50% {left:-30%;}
  50.01% {left:130%;}
  100%  {left:50%;}
}

div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left:50%;
  background-color: red;
  animation: example 4s linear infinite;
}
```

edited:

I found a better solution
Using just 2 keyframes and setting delay you can have it start anywhere on the screen.

```
@keyframes example {
  0%   {left:110%;}
  100%  {left:-10%;}
}

div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left:0%;
  background-color: red;
  animation: example 4s linear infinite;
}
```

then ethier in css on on the div itself set a delay -2 secs on a 4 secs loop will start in the centre of element.

```
<div style="animation-delay:-2s"/>
```

Comment: this still has the snappy reset of the animation

Comment: sorry never used it before didn't notice it was restarting at 50% new keyframes uses full width

Comment: this works for a single div, the problem i have is that the different icons are positioned across the width of a screen, meaning their 100% are different from eachother. since i use flex and justify-content, the left at 0% sin't necessary aswell

Comment: you can add animation delays to each div <div style="animation-delay: -2s"/>